# API Request Function Clean Up AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing an API Request using AngularJS that receives current live promotional offers that are available for a certain market. Market's are organized by ADI.

Not all markets will have multiple offers **LIVE** at any given moment, so I am having trouble distinguishing that. Sometimes there will be 0, 1 or even 2 but that is the most that a market can have live at the same time. If you see my code below you can notice my API call, then based on my response, I go in and get more properties like the expiration date, campaign state, and etc.

So for markets that have one 1 offer live, it gives me an error because it will trying to loop through and find the [1]. How do you recommend cleaning this function up so that I can not have errors if the market does not have multiple live offers.

You will also notice a property **is_primary**, I want to change that to a boolean value. So if the answer is equals to 1, then make the answer true, so that I can just display that on the front end. If the answer equals to 0 then its false.

```
$scope.offersNow = function () {
    if (offer.campaign_state === 'live') {
        var config = { method: 'get', url : $scope.config.url + '/offers/' + $scope.offer.market_adi};
        console.log($scope.offer.market_adi);
        $http(config).success(function(response, status){
            if(status === 200) {

                if (response.length > 0) {
                    response[1].Expiration_Date = moment.utc(response[1].Expiration_Date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                    response[1].isPrimary = response[1].is_primary;
                    console.log(response[1]);
                    console.log(response[1].isPrimary);
                    console.log(response[1].Expiration_Date);
                }

                console.log(response.length);

                response[0].Expiration_Date = moment.utc(response[0].Expiration_Date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                response[0].isPrimary = response[0].is_primary;

                console.log(response[0]);
                console.log(response[0].isPrimary);
                console.log(response[0].Expiration_Date);

            }
            else{
                alert("Is Not Working");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

What do you suggest doing at this point that will make my code more efficient and will work in many other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to loop through the response array and add any additional properties. You also don't need to check if the length is greater than 0 with the map function.

```
$scope.offersNow = function () {
    if (offer.campaign_state === 'live') {
        var config = { method: 'get', url : $scope.config.url + '/offers/' + $scope.offer.market_adi};
        console.log($scope.offer.market_adi);
        $http(config).success(function(response, status){
            if(status === 200) {
                response.map(function(offer, index, arr) {
                    offer.Expiration_Date = moment.utc(offer.Expiration_Date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                    offer.isPrimary = offer.is_primary;
                    console.log(offer);
                    console.log(offer.isPrimary);
                    console.log(offer.Expiration_Date);
                    return offer;
                 }
            }
            else{
                alert("Is Not Working");
            }
        });
    }
};
```